# Los valores fundamentales de Stack Overflow en español

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, centro-de-ayuda

Muchas gracias a [@lois6b](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15855/lois6b) por la traducción.

---

Los valores fundamentales de una comunidad son aquellos principios y heurísticas que usamos para tomar decisiones más complejas. Proporcionan una base para entender las normas de la comunidad. Los valores fundamentales pasan de usuarios experimentados a nuevos usuarios cuando ambos interactúan con el sistema.

Permitidnos echar un vistazo a nuestros valores fundamentales juntos, discutir sobre ellos y añadirlos al Centro de Ayuda. Esto debería ayudar a mantener la sabiduría de nuestra comunidad a largo plazo y aumentar la efectividad del aprendizaje de los nuevos usuarios acorde a los estándares de la comunidad.

Hay tres valores fundamentales que son comunes a todos los sitios internacionales de Stack Overflow:

## 1. Las personas primero

- **Relaciones grupales - Cómo nos tratamos los unos a los otros es la clave para el éxito**. La meta principal es crear y apoyar a la comunidad. El resto vendrá solo.
- **Cualquier interacción en el sitio empieza por el respeto mutuo hacia nuestros compañeros**, independientemente de las circunstancias, reputación, conocimiento u otras cosas.
- En nuestra comunidad, **[todo el mundo se siente cómodo y bienvenido](/conduct) cuando preguntan, responden o comentan.**

## 2. Cuanto mayor *buen* conocimiento en español sobre programación, ¡mejor!

- **Stack Overflow es una biblioteca de soluciones preparadas y listas** representadas en forma de problema (pregunta) y soluciones (respuestas), de la forma más pura y con el menor ruido posible.
- **Las preguntas y respuestas son escritas una vez y leídas millones de veces**. Todo el contenido del sitio está optimizado para su lectura, para desarrolladores que vienen al sitio buscando información.
- **Tener contenido útil para la comunidad es clave; cómo es creado es secundario**. Es bien recibido cualquier método para crear conocimiento *útil* en el sitio, excepto el plagio. Métodos aceptados como:

  - [Buenas prácticas, en el formato de preguntas autorespondidas](/help/self-answer).
  - [Traducciones de preguntas de otros sitios e idiomas](/help/translate-from-english).
  - Preguntas de wiki de comunidad.

  y, por supuesto, [tus problemas particulares](/help/how-to-ask), para los cuales encontraremos respuestas juntos.

## 3. Juntos por el bien de la comunidad

- **Stack Overflow es un esfuerzo colectivo para crear más y mejor conocimiento sobre programación**. El sitio existe gracias a la colaboración de muchos usuarios activos, como tú, y no [solo una única gran persona](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teor%C3%ADa_del_Gran_Hombre).
- **Juntos creamos conocimiento útil para la comunidad de habla española entera**. Cualquier desarrollador de habla española que tenga un problema puede usar las respuestas del sitio de forma gratuita.
- **La comunidad misma es el resultado de la colaboración**. Juntos decidimos el futuro de nuestro sitio y la comunidad en Meta.

---

Por favor, comparte con la comunidad qué valores principales consideras importantes y qué valores, de los descritos arriba, crees que no son valores fundamentales para la comunidad. ¿Qué cambios harías al texto de arriba, antes de añadirlos al Centro de Ayuda?

¡Agrecería cualquier opinión, comentario, ideas o sugerencias! Vamos a hacer, juntos, de este sitio, un sitio mejor.

---

**Update**

Thank you everyone who participated! The new help center article is located on: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values. Please ping me if you see something is wrong (especially the title)!

Comment: @lois6b muchas gracias y buen trabajo con la traducción.

Comment: y a @fedorqui por mis gazapos!! ^^'

Comment: (Sorry for Google Translate) ¿Podría decirme si cree que estamos listos para agregar un nuevo artículo del centro de ayuda según la discusión

Answer (score 24):

Me jubilé en el año 2012, después de 40 años de vida profesional dedicada a la mecánica. Siempre había tenido la inquietud de introducirme en el mundo de la programación informática y especialmente en todo lo relacionado con el análisis de datos.

En esta nueva fase de mi vida, a uno ya no le importan los títulos ni el trabajo programado supeditado al calendario. Los recursos que he encontrado en Internet, me han permitido introducirme en esta hermosa ciencia, trazarme un camino de aprendizaje e ir sacándolo adelante, a mi propio ritmo, plenamente satisfactorio y exitoso. En este camino, StackOverflow se ha constituido en mi mejor profesor e imprescindible ayuda.

Gracias por haber sido capaces de desarrollar un idea de aprendizaje y colaboración tan hermosa.